# Excel: Count Total Schedules at 30 minute intervals

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I'm trying to find a way to calculate how many people are available at every 30 minute interval in a day, based on their start time and end time.

For example, if 4 people come in at 7:00 AM and leave at 3:00 PM and 3 Come in at 8:00 AM and leave at 4:00 PM then that means;

```
7:00 AM = 4
7:30 AM = 4
8:00 AM = 7
8:30 AM = 7
```

and so on.

but of course, once 3:00 PM is here, it would be something like this.

```
2:30 PM = 7
3:00 PM = 3
3:30 PM = 3
```

and so on.

I have column A with the "Start Times" and Column B with "Exit Times" based on everyone's schedules

Here's some sample schedules data

```
In        Out
7:00 AM   3:00 PM
7:00 AM   1:00 PM
7:00 AM   3:00 PM
7:00 AM   3:00 PM
8:00 AM   1:00 PM
8:00 AM   2:00 PM
8:00 AM   4:00 PM
8:00 AM   4:00 PM
8:00 AM   4:00 PM
8:00 AM   4:00 PM
8:00 AM   4:00 PM
8:00 AM   2:00 PM
8:00 AM   3:00 PM
8:00 AM   4:00 PM
9:00 AM   4:00 PM
9:00 AM   5:00 PM
9:00 AM  5:00 PM
9:00 AM  5:00 PM
9:00 AM   5:00 PM
9:00 AM   5:00 PM
9:00 AM   5:00 PM
9:00 AM   5:00 PM
9:00 AM   5:00 PM
9:00 AM   5:00 PM
9:00 AM   5:00 PM
9:00 AM   5:00 PM
9:00 AM   5:00 PM
9:00 AM   5:00 PM
9:00 AM   5:00 PM
10:00 AM  6:00 PM
10:00 AM  6:00 PM
10:00 AM  6:00 PM
10:00 AM  6:00 PM
10:00 AM  6:00 PM
```

then on Column D I have all 24-hour 30 minute intervals in the following format.

```
12:00 AM
12:30 AM
1:00 AM
1:30 AM
2:00 AM
2:30 AM
3:00 AM
3:30 AM
4:00 AM
4:30 AM
5:00 AM
5:30 AM
6:00 AM
6:30 AM
7:00 AM
7:30 AM
8:00 AM
8:30 AM
9:00 AM
9:30 AM
10:00 AM
10:30 AM
11:00 AM
11:30 AM
12:00 PM
12:30 PM
1:00 PM
1:30 PM
2:00 PM
2:30 PM
3:00 PM
3:30 PM
4:00 PM
4:30 PM
5:00 PM
5:30 PM
6:00 PM
6:30 PM
7:00 PM
7:30 PM
8:00 PM
8:30 PM
9:00 PM
9:30 PM
10:00 PM
10:30 PM
11:00 PM
11:30 PM
```

I could manually do this but I'm trying to avoid this by making it simpler just copy-pasting everyone's schedules in columns A and B and have the the results displayed in column E (next to D)

I have been doing this manually but the more people and more schedules arrive, it gets a little more frustrating to continue to calculate this manually.

I don't mind if this could be done using formulas or VBA.

The only thing I've been able to do so far is to COUNTIF how many schedule start each hour =COUNTIF(A:A, D2) and how many end each hour =COUNTIF(B:B, D2) and it simply makes it easier for the rest of the manual work but other than that, I can't think of a way to do everything before mentioned.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `COUNTIFS` in E2 copied down - assuming all shifts on the same day

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<="&D2,B:B,">"&D2)`

If you have shifts that pass midnight like `18:00-02:00` then try this version

`=SUMPRODUCT(((A$2:A$1000<=D2)+(B$2:B$1000>D2)+(A$2:A$1000>B$2:B$1000)=2)+0)`

Assuming up to 1000 rows of data, adjust as required

Comment: Thank you. It partially works. I get 0's from 11:00 PM until 6:30 AM although I have schedules that end at 2:00 AM.

Comment: I assumed from your example that all shifts started and ended on the same day - the suggested formula won't work for shifts that pass midnight - I added another version for that scenario

Comment: Yeah I forgot to include those in the sample. The new formula works. I did manual calculations and compared to the results of the formula and it's all good. Thank you! Just a quick question, will it need to be modified if there are schedules that end at 3:00 AM?

Comment: No that version works for any shifts - the "=2" at the end isn't linked to any specific times - if it works for you can you please accept my answer, thanks